# getting Error invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql

Hi i am new to Sql here i have table like this

```
ID  | Name
   1    a
   2    a
   3    h
   4    e
   5    d
   6    d
```

wanted output should be

```
  name  | IDS
   a    1,2
   d    5,6
```

i had tried but throwing error

```
select distinct  ID, (select CAST(t.ID AS VARCHAR(10)) +','
            from tbl t
            where t.ID=tb.ID
            for xml path('')) name
from tbl tb
group by name
```

below error:

```
invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

can any one suggest me to wirte query please thanks in advance

Comment: write    )AS name from tbl tb group by name

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL, but you are using SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL

```
select name, group_concat(t.id)
from tbl tb
group by name
having count(*) > 1;
```

In SQL Server:

```
select name, 
       stuff((select ',' + CAST(t.ID AS VARCHAR(255))
              from tbl t
              where t.name = tb.name
              for xml path('')
             ), 1, 1, '') name
from tbl tb
group by name
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Gordon LinOff but throwing same error

Comment: invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Sadda-shutu . . . That is because the correlation needs to be on `id` rather than `name`.